# Rails addClass to the most recent data entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table of names. They are ordered randomly. I would like to highlight the name which has the latest created_at value by adding a class to its table row. So far I came up with creating an invisible column with hidden created_at values and then jQuerying the needed row, but it doesn't sound so good.

A better solution, perhaps?

Edit 1: actually, I would like to highlight the latest added entry for a certain amount of time, ideally only after the name was added. On the next reload/visit all of the rows have to be identically styled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a data attribute to each row with the created_at value and then jQuerying the needed row?

```
<tr data-created-at="#{<%= object.created_at %>}">...</tr>
```

That way you don't need an additional invisible column, hope this helps

Comment: Sneaky! I will try that in a while and tell you how it went

Comment: Cool man, hope it helps! Also, something else that's useful is [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) instead of jQuery for sorting, check it out